# Where is the 'detail flood fill' option in blender 2.9?

Tags: dynamic-topology

I wanted to try it out but I can't find it.

Comment: Hello :). [Blender Manual - Dyntopo](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/dyntopo.html) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the manual said, you just need to select Dynotopo > Detailing> Constant Detail
And you will see the option below

[image]